# Read from multiple Kafka partitions and recover original order

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing

I'm working on a system that uses Kafka as a distributed commit log. The single threaded Kafka producer receives requests from the outside, processes them and writes result to a topic with 4096 partitions. Number of partitions are chosen based on downstream consumer requirements. The producer has internal state which evolves as it receives new requests, it saves state snapshots from time to time.

In rare cases when the the producer needs to recover it reads the snapshot and then it needs to read messages from the Kafka topic in the order it has generated them. I know this is not how Kafka designed to work. But since this is a special and rare case I want to know if I can read one batch at a time from each partition, order them in memory and then apply to the snapshot to end up with up-to-date state?

Edit: Things to keep in mind. 1. All produced message carry sequence number so I can order them. 2. Producer is single threaded by design.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "batch from each partition means". Sure, you can assign partitions to *consumers* (not producers) and poll once, then move on to the next partition and repeat...

Comment: @OneCricketeer because I want to use Kafka as a "commit log" I need to a) write to it and b) read from it at restore time. Usually my producer writes, but when it recover it became a consumer. The question really is if there is a reliable way to read from multiple partitions and somehow get records in the order they were producer assuming each record has a sequence.

Comment: All data already has an offset sequence. But ordering across multiple partitions is not a pattern encouraged by kafka. I will point out Kafka Streams KTables already do what you're asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually implement this, but it's not going to be idiomatic or particularly performant (i.e. you should consider using a datastore designed for event sourcing).

The basic idea would be for your producer process to maintain offsets for the partitions as part of the snapshot (a consumer group could also be used, potentially, though care should be taken to ensure that that consumer is live within the retention period of the offsets topic, otherwise a situation where this producer is "too reliable" can lead to a nasty surprise) and then have a consumer seek to those partition offsets, read N messages  (e.g. via a `poll`) from each partition, take the lowest continuous run of sequence numbers from the consolidated 4096*N messages and then iterate until you've hit the max offset on each partition.

You will want to be careful around Kafka's message duplication guarantees: at least  you have the sequence numbers to dedupe.

The performance of this will depend on how often you snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Why do you think it is not going to be performant? Consumers poll data as fast as they could, the only thing is they process data only as soon as they have continuous chunk of it.

Comment: Compared to a setup which stores the messages linearly (with perhaps a downstream process that takes the linear messages for recovery and fans them out to the 4096 partitions, though I'd really question the need for 4096 partitions: if you're thinking of more than low double-figures of partitions in a topic, I'd seriously revisit how you're structuring the consumer side) this is going to be somewhat slower.